# What is the term for an item that facilitates the tying of things together?

Tags: terminology, names

Is there some piece of equipment or item that allows you to tie two or more

1. strands of rope
2. threads of fabric

together? I imagine that (1) and (2) will be different items. If such things do exist, what are they called?

Comment: Do you mean tie in a knot? Or tie together like a coupler (end-to-end)? Or something else entirely? And for what purpose do you imagine you would be you tying up these items?

Comment: Tie in a knot or end-to-end: just something to secure two or more strands or threads together.

Comment: How about a **fastener**?

Comment: Are you asking about reality or about if there is a single word for such a concept? Why can't you just tie the two of them together without anything else, like a _knot_? You're talking about an additional thing? Then you'll need to explain more, maybe a picture would help (use google images to find what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For rope (at least in sailing), this is called [splicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_splicing) (rope splicing) and the primary tool used is a [marlinspike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlinspike). When you're connecting frayed ropes using another piece of (usually thinner) rope this is known as [whipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlinespike_seamanship) but *real* splicing involves unlaying the rope (similar to unbraiding) and then laying in new line. See various splices in the diagram below:
[image: rope splicing]

Answer (score 0):

There is a process for fabric called *reweaving* to repair various types of holes but doesn't actually involve "tying". There are several approaches to reweaving discussed [here](http://www.withoutatrace.com/reweaving.html).